# How do I compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot p^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

I have no idea how to compute this infinite sum. It seems to pass the convergence test. It even seems to be equal to $\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}$, but I cannot prove it. Any insightful piece of advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This is almost the derivative of a serie you should know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $|p|<1$.

**METHOD $1$:**

$$p\left(\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp^k$$

---

**METHOD $2$:**

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^k&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p^k\sum_{j=1}^k (1)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}p^k\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^j}{1-p}\\\\
&=\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: You probably meant $\frac{d}{dp}$ instead of $\frac{d}{dx}$

Comment: Convergence test passed means $|p|<1$.

Comment: @Aniket Yes, that is an obvious presumption, is it not?

Comment: @Brenton Yes, of course.  Thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^k=p\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}(1-p)^2\sum_{k\geq 1}kp^k &=& \sum_{k\geq 1}kp^k -2\sum_{k\geq 1}kp^{k+1} +\sum_{k\geq 1} kp^{k+2}\\&=&(p+2p^2)-(2p^2)+\sum_{k\geq 3}\left(k-2(k-1)+(k-2)\right)p^{k}\\&=&\color{red}{p}.\end{eqnarray*}$$