# Convergence of series n/2^(n-1)

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have to find the value of
3.9^1/2.27^1/4.81^1/8....upto infinity
The series can be written as 3^£n/2^(n-1) where n is upto infinity.
I solved the question and found that n/2^(n-1)=0
Is this correct?
or I am doing wrong?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333192/solve-sum-nxn and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: There are several ways to tackle this question, one of which is to study the series $\sum nx^n$, and this series (sum) can be found by studying again the series $\sum x^n, |x| < 1$ which is "geometric"...