# How to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1)z^k}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-product

How to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1)z^k}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1$

I believe that I have to use the cauchy product?

But how do transform the expression to be a product in the first place?

Comment: Differentiate termwise...

Comment: Hint: try differentiating a well-known series. Or see [Solve $\sum nx^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333192/solve-sum-nxn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention Cauchy product, but don't say what you try. Let $(1-z)^{-1} = \sum a_{n} z^{n} = \sum b_{n} z^{n}$.

Then, in the usual notation, 
\begin{align*}
(1-z)^{-2} &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n}\right) \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}z^{n} \\
\text{where}\quad c_{n}&= \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}b_{n-i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n}1 \\
&= n+1
\end{align*}

exactly as required.

Comment: Does the part underneath $\text{where} \ldots$ also belong to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}z^{n}$, so that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}z^{n}=n+1$ where $c_{n}= \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}b_{n-i}$

Comment: Nope! Each time I write a new LHS all the RHSs until the next LHS belong to it

Comment: (also, $n$ is of course not a free variable in the first few lines, so it can't be free in any equal lines)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\,,\,\,|z|<1\implies f'(z)=\frac1{(1-z)^2}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\right)'\,,\,|z|<1\ldots$$