# find the sum of infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n$

Tags: summation, power-series

How to find the sum of infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n$? I have no clue where to begin with.

Comment: Start with the geometric series.

Comment: In particular, take the derivative of the geometric series. But other than that, you should really search the site for answers to your question -- I've seen this asked and answered quite a few times already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $\sum nx^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333192/solve-sum-nxn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of a power series $n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn)