# Sum of a series of the form n a^n

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I was playing around with geometric series and I wondered if it was possible to find a formula for the sum of an altered geometric series (which actually stops being geometric) of the form:

$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N}na^n$

Under the condition $1>a>0$

Is there a way to compute this sum other than summing term by term? Can we find a formula that depends on $N$ and $a$ for this sum?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $\sum nx^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333192/solve-sum-nxn)

Comment: That other one is an infinite series, but this is a finite series.  But the idea should be the same.

Comment: Hint: $$
na^n  = a\frac{d}{{da}}a^n .
$$

Comment: There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence)  To get a finite series you can subtract a short infinite sequence from a longer one.